# How to map over function with multiple arguments (and changing data)?

Tags: r, dataframe, purrr, gt

I am creating a function to create gt tables for individual states within a data frame at the state-city level. I will be changing the data often as well as the selected columns in the gt, so I added a number of input arguments to the function call so that I can change it and use it accordingly. I want to use the purrr::map function as a pseudo for loop to iterate the function over data, while having the freedom to change the inputted data sources and selected columns within the gts.

The problem is that when I try to use the map function to get it to iterate over the data, I don't know how to change the map function to accommodate the multiple inputs.

How can I change the map function to do this? In this case, how can I use the function I've written to create an individual gt for each of the states in the example data? If there is an different/easier way of accomplishing this any suggestions are appreciated. Here's what I have tried:

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

## WRITE THE FUNCTION
make_gts <- function(df, x, def_var, select_vect, title_text){
  
  df_ind <- df %>% filter(def_var == x)
  
  df_ind_clean <- df_ind %>% 
    select(all_of(select_vect)) 
    
  gt(df_ind_clean) %>% 
    tab_header(title = paste("This is a GT for", title_text))
    
  return(gt)
}

## DEFINE ARGUMENTS OF THE FUNCTION
title_text = "Elevation and NumObserved"
select_vect <- c("City", "Elevation", "NumObserved")
def_var <- df$State

## CREATE MAP LIST
iterate_list <- unique(def_var)

## GT LIST
state_gt_list <- set_names(iterate_list) %>% 
  purrr:map(make_gts(df = ex_data,
                     def_var = df$State, 
                     x = iterate_list[i], 
                     select_vect = select_vect,
                     title_text = title_text))
```

Sample data:

```
df <- structure(list(State = c("California", "California", "California", 
"Texas", "Texas", "Texas", "New Mexico", "New Mexico", "New Mexico"
), City = c("Los Angeles", "San Francisco", "Fresno", "Dallas", 
"Austin", "Frisco", "Albuquerque", "Santa Fe", "Taos"), NumObserved = c(1200000L, 
825000L, 113000L, 240000L, 189000L, 38000L, 56000L, 23000L, 6000L
), Elevation = c(28L, 47L, 235L, 312L, 550L, 128L, 4291L, 3533L, 
7823L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Ideally the output would be a list containing a gt for each state:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Group your `df` by `State`.  Use `group_map` to execute your function.

Comment: It's not super clear what you are iterating over in your example. What exactly is the desired output? Are you trying to update the values of `iterate_list[i]` since `i` doesn't seem to be defined here?

Comment: Doing the selecting in the function makes sense, but don't do filtering in the function. Only pass rows to the function that you want included. Then you can do something like `ex_data %>% group_by(State) %>% group_map(make_gts, ...)`

Comment: @MrFlick I want it to iterate over iterate_list (which is a vector of unique States), but I don't know how to iterate it. I'm not trying to update the values of iterate_list, I just put `x = iterate_list[i]` in as a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, and returning a standard tibble, since I don't have the `gt` package...

```
df %>% 
  group_by(State) %>% 
  group_map(
    function(.x, .y, select_vect) {
      df_ind_clean <- .x %>% 
              select(all_of(select_vect)) 
      # gt(df_ind_clean) %>% 
      #   tab_header(title = paste("This is a GT for", title_text))
      # return(gt)
      df_ind_clean
    },
    select_vect=c("City", "Elevation", "NumObserved")
  )
```

gives

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  City          Elevation NumObserved
  <chr>             <int>       <int>
1 Los Angeles          28     1200000
2 San Francisco        47      825000
3 Fresno              235      113000

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  City        Elevation NumObserved
  <chr>           <int>       <int>
1 Albuquerque      4291       56000
2 Santa Fe         3533       23000
3 Taos             7823        6000

[[3]]
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  City   Elevation NumObserved
  <chr>      <int>       <int>
1 Dallas       312      240000
2 Austin       550      189000
3 Frisco       128       38000
```

Is that close to what you want?

Next time, please create a minimal reproducible example.  As well as code and test data, an MRE includes *expected output* and references all packages required to run your code.

Comment: Updated the post, per your request. The output you created is pretty much what I want...however, is there any way to wrap your code in a function so that i can reproduce it quickly for different data sets? I tried this code, but am getting a gt with all states in it:

Comment: df <- ex_data
group_var <-"State"

create_gts_and_map <- function(df, group_var) {
  df %>% 
    group_by(df$group_var) %>% 
    group_map(
      function(.x, .y, select_vect) {
        df_ind_clean <- .x %>% 
          select(all_of(select_vect)) 
        gt <- gt(df_ind_clean) %>% 
          tab_header(title = paste("This is a GT for", title_text))
        return(gt)
        #df_ind_clean
      },
      select_vect=c("City", "Elevation", "NumObserved")
    )
}

gt_list <- create_gts_and_map(df = df, group_var = group_var)

Comment: If you delete my `df_ind_clean` and uncomment your `gt` codse, then my code should give you exactly what you need.  I don't see what you need to wrap it in a function for.  (You can get the `State` name from the `.y` parameter to the function called by `group_map`.)

Comment: wouldn't it be easiest to wrap it in a function so that I can create GTs for different data sets? then I could just change the vector of selected columns and the title with the `title_text` argument?